# Xcode Build Failure: "React Native Build Issues on iOS. Xcode Error Code 65 and AppDelegate.m Selector Error"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mern

**Context:**

USING MERN STACK.

I have a React Native project that was initiated in 2021. It used to run without issues using npm install, npx pod-install, and npm run ios. However, since May 2023, I've encountered multiple errors and dependency problems, potentially due to Xcode or macOS updates.

After updating the project's dependencies to resolve the initial errors, I am now stuck with a final build error that I can't seem to resolve. Running the project through Xcode (opening MYVU.xcworkspace) yields a different error. Below are the details of the errors I'm currently facing.

**Errors:**

**1. Terminal Error on npm run ios:**
At the start, I receive the usual build process logs, but it ends with:

"error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening MYVU.xcworkspace.
"

The specific build command failure is:
"The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/bolt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYVU-azqcqluibbqvqnguxonkqyoewstd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SysUio.o /Users/bolt/Desktop/myvu-mobile-main/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/portability/SysUio.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)"
[The specific build command failure is:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD3e8.png)

**2. Xcode Error in AppDelegate.m:**
When running the project directly from Xcode (MYVU.xcworkspace), I encounter this error in AppDelegate.m:

["No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider' declares the selector 'jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:'"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sk2L.png)

**Environment:**

React Native Version: 18.2.0
Xcode Version: 15.0.1
macOS Version: Sonoma 14.1.1
Node Version: v21.1.0

**Attempts to Resolve:**

Updated project dependencies to latest versions.
Cleaned build folder and deleted derived data in Xcode.
Tried resetting iOS simulators.
Searched for similar issues but couldn't find a solution that fits.

**Expected:**

The Simulator should open and build the app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the post:

Android builds without issue, but for iOS build I saw something similar:

❯ npm run ios

```
> AwesomeProject@0.0.1 ios
> react-native run-ios

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Found Xcode workspace "AwesomeProject.xcworkspace"
info Found booted iPhone 15
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace AwesomeProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=055DD7C2-843A-4686-8FA0-0A05DD0446C2")
▸ Running script '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed'
▸ Running script '[CP-User] Generate Specs'
▸ Compiling react_native_log.cpp
▸ Compiling MapBuffer.cpp
▸ Compiling DebugStringConvertible.cpp
▸ Compiling InspectorInterfaces.cpp
▸ Compiling AssertFatal.cpp
▸ Compiling RunLoopObserver.cpp
▸ Compiling ManagedObjectWrapper.mm
▸ Compiling JSIDynamic.cpp
▸ Compiling JsErrorHandler.cpp
    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 

error Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code '65'. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening 'AwesomeProject.xcworkspace'.
```

p.s. RN 0.72.8 works for me without issues.

Comment: Potentially related regarding the "Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed" warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78233461/333325