# React Native iOS won't build because of Flipper or Hermes Engine

Tags: ios, react-native, flipper

I face this issue and I do not have any clue about what is cause the problem.

It's about a React Native App, I didn't install anything from days or change code. It's happen from the moment I update my macOS Ventura to Sonoma.

````
    [VisionCamera] node modules found at /Users/[USER]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/react-native/..
    [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors disabled!
    Auto-linking React Native modules for target `ReactNativeMobile`: BVLinearGradient, RNCAsyncStorage, RNCClipboard, RNLocalize, RNReanimated, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNSha256, VisionCamera, react-native-config, react-native-get-random-values, react-native-passkey, react-native-quick-crypto, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-splash-screen, and react-native-webview
    Framework build type is static library
    [Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
    [Codegen] generating an empty RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider
    Analyzing dependencies
    Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
    [Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
    Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`
    [Codegen] Found rncore
    [VisionCamera] node modules found at /Users/[USER]/[PROJECT]/node_modules/react-native/..
    [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors disabled!
    Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
    Fetching podspec for `hermes-engine` from `../node_modules/react-native/sdks/hermes-engine/hermes-engine.podspec`
    [Hermes] Using release tarball from URL: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-native-artifacts/0.73.1/react-native-artifacts-0.73.1-hermes-ios-debug.tar.gz
    Downloading dependencies
    Installing BVLinearGradient (2.8.3)
    Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)
    Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
    Installing FBLazyVector (0.73.1)
    Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.73.1)
    Installing Flipper (0.201.0)
    Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)
    Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.2.0.1)
    Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
    Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.10)
    Installing Flipper-Glog (0.5.0.5)
    Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
    Installing FlipperKit (0.201.0)
    Installing OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.1100)
    Installing RCT-Folly (2022.05.16.00)
    Installing RCTRequired (0.73.1)
    Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.73.1)
    Installing RNCAsyncStorage (1.21.0)
    Installing RNCClipboard (1.13.2)
    // HERE WAS MORE
    Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.73.1)
    Installing React-runtimescheduler (0.73.1)
    Installing React-utils (0.73.1)
    Installing ReactCommon (0.73.1)
    Installing SocketRocket (0.6.1)
    Installing VisionCamera (3.8.2)
    Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
    Installing boost (1.83.0)
    Installing fmt (6.2.1)
    Installing glog (0.3.5)
    Installing hermes-engine (0.73.1)

    [!] Error installing hermes-engine

    ――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    ### Command

    ```
    /usr/local/bin/pod install
    ```

    ### Report

    * What did you do?

    * What did you expect to happen?

    * What happened instead?


    ### Stack

    ```
      CocoaPods : 1.15.0
            Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin23]
        RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
            Host : macOS 14.3 (******)
          Xcode : 15.2 (******)
            Git : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-145)
    Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
    Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
    ```

    ### Plugins

    ```
    cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
    cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
    cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
    cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
    cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
    ```

    ### Podfile

    ```ruby
    # Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
    require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
      'require.resolve(
        "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
        {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
      )', __dir__]).strip

    platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
    prepare_react_native_project!

    # If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
    # because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
    #
    # To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
    # ```js
    # module.exports = {
    #   dependencies: {
    #     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
    # ```
    flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.enabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

    linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
    if linkage != nil
      Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
      use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
    end

    target 'ReactNativeMobile' do
      config = use_native_modules!

      use_react_native!(
        :path => config[:reactNativePath],
        # Enables Flipper.
        #
        # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
        # you should disable the next line.
        :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
        # An absolute path to your application root.
        :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
      )

      target 'ReactNativeMobileTests' do
        inherit! :complete
        # Pods for testing
      end

      post_install do |installer|
        # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
        react_native_post_install(
          installer,
          config[:reactNativePath],
          :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
        )
      end
    end
    ```

    ### Error

    ```
    Errno::EEXIST - File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - /Users/[USER]/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/hermes-engine/0e37d787f1d5a7b711e72349208731c3-34df9/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst/hermes.framework/Resources
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1365:in `symlink'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1365:in `copy'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:478:in `block in copy_entry'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1485:in `wrap_traverse'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1488:in `block in wrap_traverse'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `each'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1487:in `wrap_traverse'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:475:in `copy_entry'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:453:in `block in cp_r'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1558:in `block in fu_each_src_dest'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1567:in `block in fu_each_src_dest0'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1565:in `each'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1565:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1556:in `fu_each_src_dest'
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:452:in `cp_r'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in copy_files'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:341:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:341:in `block in copy_files'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:128:in `lock'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:99:in `write_lock'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:332:in `copy_files'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:269:in `block (2 levels) in uncached_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:265:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:265:in `block in uncached_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:291:in `in_tmpdir'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:238:in `uncached_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:33:in `download_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:42:in `download'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_downloader.rb:69:in `download!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:67:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `install_source_of_pod'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    ```

    ――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

    [!] Oh no, an error occurred.

    Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=File+exists+%40+syserr_fail2_in+-+%2FUsers%2F[USER]%2FLibrary%2FCaches%2FCocoaPods%2FPods%2FExternal%2Fhermes-engine%2F0e37d787f1d5a7b711e72349208731c3-34df9%2Fdestroot%2FLibrary%2FFrameworks%2Funiversal%2Fhermes.xcframework%2Fios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst%2Fhermes.framework%2FResources&type=Issues

    If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

    Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
    https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

    Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

    Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
    Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
    https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new
````

I tried clean the cache of Node, delete the node_module and package-lock then reinstall everything.
I tried the same with Cocoapods.
I looked on Google.
Nothing help me to found a way.

And now StackOverflow continu to ask me to add some details because I have to much code on my text... Thanks to make me life bad. So I delete some package from the list, sorry.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- The native module for Flipper seems unavailable. Please verify that react-native-flipper is installed : https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/1253
- React Native 0.70.0 iOs fresh project errors out on run-ios : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34608
- It seems like you are encountering an issue while installing the hermes-engine during the CocoaPods installation process for your React Native project.

  ```
   pod cache clean --all

   sudo gem install cocoapods
  ```
- Manually installing the hermes-engine by downloading the source code from the GitHub repository (https://github.com/facebook/hermes/releases) and adding it to your project

  ```
  Use use_react_native!(
  Set :path => config[:reactNativePath]
  Change false to true or true to false to enable or disable Hermes on iOS
  pod deintegrate && pod install
  ```

Comment: Thank to you, I answer but it's on top of yours. I have a next issue...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @Pratik.

I wasn't sure what you want to point first, but after a while, reading and looking your links I found one solution works for me here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29605#issuecomment-861783673

Now, because I can install all Pods I need, I run this command : `npm run ios`

But one "original" error show up (original because it was my first problem before I'am trying to found a solution on Google - which give me the error I show first on this page).

Here it's what I get on Terminal (I cut some lines because I have 1600 lines)

```
    > app-beta@0.0.1 ios
    > react-native run-ios --simulator=iPhone 15 Pro (16.0)
    
    info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
    info Found Xcode workspace "ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace"
    info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeMobile -destination id=369F7481-D15C-42EF-8D3A-9D52FB544F6A")
    
    info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 
    
    node:internal/process/promises:289
                triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
                ^
    
    [Command line invocation:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace ReactNativeMobile.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme ReactNativeMobile -destination id=369F7481-D15C-42EF-8D3A-9D52FB544F6A
    
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    Prepare packages
    
    ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    note: Target dependency graph (80 targets)
        // MORE MORE TARGET LINES
        Target 'hermes-engine' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'React-callinvoker' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'React-Core-RCTI18nStrings' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods'
            ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods'
            ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'boost' in project 'Pods'
            ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'fmt' in project 'Pods'
            ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'glog' in project 'Pods'
            ➜ Explicit dependency on target 'libevent' in project 'Pods'
        Target 'libevent' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'glog' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'fmt' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'boost' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
        Target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' (no dependencies)
    
    GatherProvisioningInputs
    
    CreateBuildDescription
    
    ClangStatCache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.2-21C52-4f2951bfe8f3cd53c99228b0131e163e.sdkstatcache
        cd /Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk -o /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator17.2-21C52-4f2951bfe8f3cd53c99228b0131e163e.sdkstatcache
    
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ [Hermes]\ Replace\ Hermes\ for\ the\ right\ configuration,\ if\ needed /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/hermes-engine.build/Script-46EB2E00022B60.sh (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
        cd /Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods
        export ACTION\=build
        // MORE MORE LINES
        export arch\=undefined_arch
        export variant\=normal
        /usr/bin/sandbox-exec -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/.xcode.env.local -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_1\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/.xcode.env -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_2\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_0\=/ -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_1\=/Users -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_2\=/Users/[USER] -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_3\=/Users/[USER]/Library -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_4\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_5\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_6\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_7\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_8\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_9\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_10\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_11\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_12\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_13\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_14\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D SRCROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D PROJECT_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D OBJROOT\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex -D SYMROOT\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products -D DSTROOT\=/tmp/ReactNativeMobile.dst -D SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -D CACHE_ROOT\=/var/folders/ff/8z0rnxqx6k9c6b_cvwb296wm0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/15.2-15C500b/Xcode -D CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -D CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator -D LOCROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D LOCSYMROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D INDEX_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Index.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -D INDEX_DATA_STORE_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Index.noindex/DataStore -D TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D TARGET_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/DerivedSources -f /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/760d9abdd9cfc4a0493653141570aa72.sb /bin/sh -c /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh
    Node found at: /usr/local/bin/node
    + DEST=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app
    + [[ ! -n '' ]]
    + [[ Debug = *Debug* ]]
    + [[ ! iphonesimulator == *simulator ]]
    + [[ -n '' ]]
    + case "$CONFIGURATION" in
    + [[ iphonesimulator == *simulator ]]
    + [[ -n '' ]]
    + echo 'Skipping bundling in Debug for the Simulator (since the packager bundles for you). Use the FORCE_BUNDLING flag to change this behavior.'
    Skipping bundling in Debug for the Simulator (since the packager bundles for you). Use the FORCE_BUNDLING flag to change this behavior.
    + exit 0
    
    GenerateDSYMFile /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app.dSYM /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/ReactNativeMobile (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
        cd /Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/ReactNativeMobile -o /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app.dSYM
    
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C.sh (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
        cd /Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios
        /usr/bin/sandbox-exec -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_1\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/glog.framework -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_2\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/OpenSSL.framework -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_3\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_0\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ReactNativeMobile/Pods-ReactNativeMobile-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_1\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ReactNativeMobile/Pods-ReactNativeMobile-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_2\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ReactNativeMobile/Pods-ReactNativeMobile-frameworks.sh -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_3\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/double-conversion -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_4\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-Glog/glog.framework/glog -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_5\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/OpenSSL-Universal/OpenSSL.framework/OpenSSL -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_6\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built/hermes.framework/hermes -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_7\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/InputFileList-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C-Pods-ReactNativeMobile-frameworks-Debug-input-files-31f1e9eccf52e56aa91725e9772fcf15-resolved.xcfilelist -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_8\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/OutputFileList-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C-Pods-ReactNativeMobile-frameworks-Debug-output-files-168748165afddb797f17bb86dec0703d-resolved.xcfilelist -D SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_9\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C.sh -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_0\=/ -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_1\=/Users -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_2\=/Users/[USER] -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_3\=/Users/[USER]/Library -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_4\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_5\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_6\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_7\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_8\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_9\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_10\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_11\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_12\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_13\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_14\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_15\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_16\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_17\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_18\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-Glog -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_19\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-Glog/glog.framework -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_20\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/OpenSSL-Universal -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_21\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/OpenSSL-Universal/OpenSSL.framework -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_22\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_23\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_24\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/hermes-engine/Pre-built/hermes.framework -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_25\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_26\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_27\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_28\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files -D SCRIPT_INPUT_ANCESTOR_29\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/Pods-ReactNativeMobile -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_0\=/ -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_1\=/Users -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_2\=/Users/[USER] -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_3\=/Users/[USER]/Library -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_4\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_5\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_6\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_7\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_8\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_9\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_10\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_11\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app -D SCRIPT_OUTPUT_ANCESTOR_12\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks -D SRCROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D PROJECT_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D OBJROOT\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex -D SYMROOT\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products -D DSTROOT\=/tmp/ReactNativeMobile.dst -D SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -D CACHE_ROOT\=/var/folders/ff/8z0rnxqx6k9c6b_cvwb296wm0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/15.2-15C500b/Xcode -D CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -D CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator -D LOCROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D LOCSYMROOT\=/Users/[USER]/react-native-mobile/ios -D INDEX_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Index.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -D INDEX_DATA_STORE_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Index.noindex/DataStore -D TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D TARGET_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build -D DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/DerivedSources -f /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/cea6d9cea052dd0bfab943f67b8ed4f6.sb /bin/sh -c /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C.sh
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39000) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39001) deny(1) file-write-times /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39000) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/Info.plist (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39002) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/double-conversion (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39002) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/.double-conversion.MsoDda (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(39001) deny(1) file-write-times /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    mkdir -p /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks
    rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework" "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks"
    building file list ... rsync: opendir "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
    done
    IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
    rsync: send_files failed to open "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/Info.plist": Operation not permitted (1)
    double-conversion.framework/double-conversion
    double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature/
    rsync: failed to set times on "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature": Operation not permitted (1)
    rsync: mkstemp "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/.double-conversion.MsoDda" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
    rsync: failed to set times on "/Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.app/Frameworks/double-conversion.framework/_CodeSignature": Operation not permitted (1)
    
    sent 465046 bytes  received 70 bytes  930232.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 465519  speedup is 1.00
    rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/4e1473ee-9f66-11ee-8daf-cedaeb4cabe2/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
    
    warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'hermes-engine' from project 'Pods')
    
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:369F7481-D15C-42EF-8D3A-9D52FB544F6A, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:369F7481-D15C-42EF-8D3A-9D52FB544F6A, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReactNativeMobile-dnbmfpcbbhsdqyffofpgineqcujk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeMobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeMobile.build/Script-DAED0FAA95522CC1681F799C.sh (in target 'ReactNativeMobile' from project 'ReactNativeMobile')
    (1 failure)
    ]
    
    Node.js v20.9.0
```

Thanks

EDIT: I do not have a project folder with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the build output that you posted you will see this:

> warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [Hermes] Replace Hermes for the right configuration, if needed'

We have run into this same message that causes our iOS build to fail. It looks to be an issue building a React Native App using 0.73.6 on iOS and we found the following related issues:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/43333

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/43285

We are not using Expo but it appears that this same issue also affects Apps using Expo 50 (which uses RN0.73)

There looks to be a bug during the `yarn install` phase when the pods are being installed which leads to a `.xcode.env.local` file being created with an incorrect node path

The temporary solution until (hopefully) a fix is provided in a further RN0.72 update is just to delete the file

```
rm ./ios/.xcode.env.local
```